# Web data grid of Infragistics controls

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I am working on a web project where I need to use WebDataGrid of Infragistics controls and customise the header layout. I did not find event like InitializeLayout in UltraWebGrid. My problem is that i want to row in header. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `WebHierarchicalDataGrid` control for representing hierarchical data structures instead `WebDataGrid`, check out the samples here http://samples.infragistics.com/aspnet/ComponentOverview.aspx?cn=hierarchical-data-grid

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this work in the UltraWebGrids InitializeLayout() handler.

Within it, access the headers like such:

```
e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.FromKey(<data field>).Header...
```

Note: a good resource for Infragistics support can be found at http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/61.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I bet Vishal meant "WebDataGrid". And for that there is no such handler, nor is there a concept of Bands. I thus have a similar problem. In fact, it is unclear to me in which event handler I have access to the header and footer rows because all the WebDataGrid control has is an InitializeRow handler which passes in reference to the Data Rows, not the header row. Thus I simply do whatever I can in the generic control Load handler.